# Book about people trying to survive in a world where technology has been shut down or destroyed

Tags: story-identification, books, post-apocalyptic

I'm looking for a specific book, but I can't find it: it was about an electrical shutdown (no, it's not *Blackout*).

The book was about a virus or something like that destroying advanced technology, and was written from the point of view of a few people. One of them was a prepper guy who first shut down in his own house for a while, and after that left the city for his safe-house, only to be found and robbed by his brother.

I remember one of the characters was a man who worked in a phone repair shop who tried to fix the phones but they came back broken. Then, further on in the book, there was a description of a family who worked next to a nuclear power plant and before escaping the master of the house killed a cat with a brick in order not to let it go to certain death. When the dams broke, the power plant broke down. Complete chaos. The police went around town and rescued people because they were the only people with guns.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year (or range of years) did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: I edited the title to capture the essence of the plot you described, as I understood it. Feel free to edit the title yourself if it doesn't align with the plot in any way, or for any other reason, if you want.

Comment: I read this max 3 years ago. About publishing I have no idea. And cover... If I remember correctly it was just big black-yellow sun eclipse. But I'm not sure.

Comment: I remember one of the characters was a man who worked in a phone repair shop who tried to fix phones but they came back broken. Then further on in the book there was a description of a family who worked next to a nuclear power plant and before escaping the master of the house killed a cat with a brick in order not to let it go to certain death, and then the dams broke, the power plant broke down. Complete chaos. The police went around town and rescued people because they were the only people with guns

Comment: "One of them was a prepper guy who first shut down in his own house for a while, and after that left the city for his safe-house, only to be found and robbed by his brother" ....did his brother rob him personally or had he already found and robbed the supplies in the safe house?